# iOS8 sharing extension completion UI

Tags: ios, ios8

I'm creating a sharing extension that uses a background NSURLSession. Is it possible to show an UIAlertController when the session has completed its tasks, seeing that the extension has been terminated and has no concept of a root view controller?

Comment: No, pretty sure it's not. You could probably trigger a local notification though.

Comment: @Kevin how would it work when you cannot obtain an instance of UIApplication? You need that to fire a local notification using  scheduleLocalNotification: or presentLocalNotificationNow:?

Comment: @JoeTam Did you ever figure this out? Is it possible to use a subclass of UIViewController without a UI and still call UIViewController.present(_:animated:) to present the UIAlertController?